# Do variable values in useEffect's cleaning function remain as they were in the last time useEffect ran?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this cleaning function:

```
  // This cleans up our listener and removes us from the latest portal we were in. Is this the right place?
  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      if (!room || !currentPortal) return;
      leavePortal(room, currentPortal, currentUserProfile.uid || uniqueId);
      detachListener();
    };
  }, [isFirstLoad]);
```

And it seems that `currentPortal`'s value reamins as it was on first load. I console log it when it changes, yet when the component unmounts it uses the initial value it had.

Comment: It looks alright. Could it be that the value of isFirstLoad didn't change?

Comment: You haven't specified any of the variables in the dependency array, so yes, they will never change value. This is related to closures. If you use a variable that is defined OUTSIDE the useEffect but INSIDE the component (like state for example) then you need to add it to the dependency array.

Comment: From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) about using a dependency array: ...make sure the array includes all values from the component scope (such as props and state) that change over time and that are used by the effect. Otherwise, your code will reference stale values from previous renders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the useEffect is only called when isFirsLoad changes, the regular updates to roo,. currentPortal and currentUserProfile will not reflect inside the useEffect cleanup.

The simplest solution is to run the cleanup whenever any one of the values change

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      if (!room || !currentPortal) return;
      leavePortal(room, currentPortal, currentUserProfile.uid || uniqueId);
      detachListener();
    };
  }, [isFirstLoad, room, currentPortal,currentUserProfile.uid, uniqueId]);
```

The solution is to make use of ref to store these variables if you don't wish to trigger a cleanup on each of these values change

```
const portalRefs = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    portalRefs.current = { room, currentPortal, uid: currentUserProfile.uid, uniqueId }
}, [room, currentPortal,currentUserProfile.uid, uniqueId])



useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      const { room, currentPortal, uid, uniqueId } = portalRefs.current;
      if (!room || !currentPortal) return;
      leavePortal(room, currentPortal, uid || uniqueId);
      detachListener();
    };
  }, [isFirstLoad]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> Experienced JavaScript developers might notice that the function passed to useEffect is going to be different on every render. This is intentional. In fact, this is what lets us read the value from inside the effect without worrying about it getting stale. Every time we re-render, we schedule a different effect, replacing the previous one. In a way, this makes the effects behave more like a part of the render result — each effect “belongs” to a particular render. We will see more clearly why this is useful later on this page.

Your useEffect dependency list is `[isFirstLoad]`,  so every time `isFirstLoad` changes a new effect with the captured value of `currentPortal` at the moment will be created.